# how to get data to highchart 'data series' in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, highcharts, controller, series

I'm a newbie programmer
I have a problem with my website program base in codeigniter
I want to input data from my database into a chart by using highchart

These My controller codes:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->view_data = array();
    $this->load->model('Siswa_model');
}

    function index(){ 
    $nis = 100065;
    $tahun = 1;
    $dt = $this->Siswa_model->dcmSiswa($nis, $tahun)->result();
    $nilai  = array(
        $dt[0]->h1,
        $dt[0]->h2,
        $dt[0]->h3
        ); echo "<pre/>"; print_r($nilai);
    $name = array('1','2', '3'); 
        /* ... continued at the bottom ... */
        }
```

these my data result when I print using `<pre/> and print_r($nilai);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 36
    [1] => 45
    [2] => 45
)
```

data has been loaded and **success** but this **is my problem**
program code below is a *continuation of the controller section above*

```
/* ... continued from the top ...  */
    for($i = 0 ; $i < 3 ; $i++){
    $series_data[] = array('name' => $name[$i], 'data' => $nilai[$i] );
    }
    $this->view_data['catagories'] = json_encode($name); 
    $this->view_data['series_data'] = json_encode($series_data); 
    $this->load->view('rubbish/cobaChart', $this->view_data);   
}
```

**I can not show my chart, except a box without contents**

these my view code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function () { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            borderWidth: 4,
            borderRadius: 30
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {

            categories: <?php echo $catagories; ?>
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
            text: 'Masalah Siswa'
            }
        },
        series: <?php echo $series_data; ?>
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

I hope you're understand what my points and my problem
thanks

Comment: Are the `$catagories` and `$series_data` variables being passed to the view correctly?

Comment: check if you get the data in console!

Comment: Set a in the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK flag in the json_encode()

Comment: @Dan yeah it passed correctly but the data won't appear in chart, but if I use print_r it work